# JPA - many-to-many as ElementCollection

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, many-to-many

I've got a many-to-many relationship that assigns labels (nothing but string) to items:

```
+------+   +------------+   +-------+
| ITEM |   | ITEM_LABEL |   | LABEL |
|------|   |------------|   |-------|
|  ID  |<->|  ITEM_ID   | ┌>|  ID   |
|------|   |------------| | |-------|
| .... |   |  LABEL_ID  |<┘ | TEXT  |
+------+   +------------+   +-------+
```

... and I'd like to avoid creating POJO class for the label table and keep it in the Item class as a collection of strings. Is there a way to do it with JPA (hibernate) annotations?

I've tried to combine @CollectionTable with @JoinTable but it obviously does not work:

```
@Entity
public class Item {

    @Id
    private long id;

    @ElementCollection
    @JoinTable(name = "ITEM_LABEL", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ITEM_ID"))
    @CollectionTable(name = "LABEL", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ID", referencedColumnName = "LABEL_ID"))
    @Column(name = "TEXT")
    private Collection<Strings> labels;
}
```

Can anyone tell me how could I include the labels as a collection of string in the item class, please? Many thanks!

Comment: I assume you have found [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19966486/hibernate-4-onetomany-liststring) and it doesn't work for you

Comment: You probably don't need the `@JoinTable` and `@Column` annotations

Comment: Hi Lino. The thread you mentioned does not deal with many-to-many relationship, so it does not solve my problem. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Did you find any solution ? I encounter the same problem. Thanks in advance

Comment: @Julien, sadly I have not. I'm 've created a class for the Label

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@JoinTable` is used to map following associations to database table: bidirectional many-to-one/one-to-many, unidirectional many-to-one, and one-to-one (both bidirectional and unidirectional) associations.

If you really want to have  `Label`with his own table you have to define it as an `Entity` and then using `ManyToMany` relation.

The other solution would be to remove `Label` table and keep label name as `LABEL` instead of label_id inside `item_label` table.

So your relation will become

```java
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name = "ITEM_LABEL", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ITEM_ID"))
@Column(name = "LABEL")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, CodeScale. It is a legacy DB and I cannot change the structure. Moreover, there are some benefits/reasons of having the label in its own table. I do have a Label entity at the moment but I'm still looking for a better solution. If I don't find it any time soon, I'll mark your answer as accepted. Thanks again!

Comment: Just to remind you that it's been more than three years now and you didn't label his answer as the accepted one, @dpelisek

Comment: I still have not found a better solution. So creating a new entity and using n:n (as you've suggested) seems to be the only way.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid creating a POJO though? I'd understand if you didn't want a Label to have its own table, but it does have a table in your design, so it's the base case for using an `@Entity`, no?